# Has "Do You Know The Way To San Jose?" been recorded in the USA?

Tags: recording, record-labels

Has Bossa Rio’s song *Do You Know The Way To San Jose?* been recorded in the USA, too?

On YouTube: [サン・ホセへの道／ボサ・リオ Do You Know The Way To San Jose／Bossa Rio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdcJf9rACHM)

Comment: Is this really an *album*? According to http://www.discogs.com/artist/269369-Bossa-Rio, *Do You Know The Way To San Jose?* is a single/EP.

Comment: @Unor It isn't. The song _Do You Know The Way To San Jose?_ is featured on the album/LP _Bossa Rio_ by Bossa Rio

Answer (score 3):

The song "[Do You Know The Way to San Jose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_You_Know_the_Way_to_San_Jose)" was written by American composer Burt Bacharach and lyricist Hal David, for American singer Dionne Warwick. The original version, with Warwick on vocals, was released in the United States in 1968.

Sergio Mendez' Brazilian band Bossa Rio released their instrumental cover of "Do You Know the Way to San Jose" one year later, in 1969.

The song has been covered by many artists, most of the in the USA, for many years. You can see the [Wikipedia article on the song here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_You_Know_the_Way_to_San_Jose#Covers).